# Why does DLookup not return the values updated during a transaction?

Tags: vba, ms-access, transactions, dlookup

I am using transactions in my MS Access VBA code. I update one of my fields, the `Incoming_Pieces` field in my Inventory table. Then, before committing the transaction, I use `DLookup` on the updated field. The `DLookup` function will return the value before the transaction, not the value updated during the transaction before committing.

Is this intended? There's no error message or any warning that the data I am retrieving is out of sync with the data being updated within the transaction.

Is the only workaround to generate a `SELECT` statement instead of DLookup?

Here's my testing code to prove this.

```
Public Function testTransaction()

    Dim pieces As Variant
    pieces = DLookup("Incoming_Pieces", "Inventory", "Code='MT-1-1000x1x1'")
    Debug.Print (pieces)    ' <------------ prints 0
    
    DAO.DBEngine.BeginTrans
    
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "UPDATE Inventory SET Incoming_Pieces = 10 WHERE Code='MT-1-1000x1x1'"
    CurrentDb.Execute (sql)
    pieces = DLookup("Incoming_Pieces", "Inventory", "Code='MT-1-1000x1x1'")
    Debug.Print (pieces)    ' <------------ prints 0

    DAO.DBEngine.CommitTrans

    pieces = DLookup("Incoming_Pieces", "Inventory", "Code='MT-1-1000x1x1'")
    Debug.Print (pieces)    ' <------------ prints 10
    
End Function
```

Comment: Apparently that is by design. Did you verify that SELECT returns updated value? Why do you even need UPDATE action? Why are you not just doing data entry of a transaction record?

Comment: Yes `SELECT` does return the updated value. This was just sample code. In my real solution. I have several SQL statements being run which need to be in a transaction. The 5th query in the transaction depends on values updated by the 1st query. There is a lot more logic to it in VBA, so it couldn't all be done with one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DLookUp` is executed in the application scope, while `BeginTrans` only affects the database engine scope, and only DAO.

In queries, we can make distinctions between 2 scopes:

1. Application. These queries can make use of user-defined functions and can refer to form-based parameters (such as `WHERE MyField = Forms!SomeForm!SomeControl`).
2. Database engine (DAO/ODBC/Others): These queries can't refer to anything happening in the application, so can't use functions defined in VBA nor form-based parameters, but are affected by transactions if the connection/workspace they operate on starts one.

If we want to query what's happening inside a transaction, we need to be in the same scope. This means you need to rewrite your `DLookUp` to use recordsets.

```
pieces = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Incoming_Pieces FROM Inventory WHERE Code='MT-1-1000x1x1'")(0).Value
```

An even more minimal example to demonstrate this:

```
DAO.DBEngine.BeginTrans
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1(Field1) VALUES(1)"
Debug.Print CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1")(0) 'Prints 1 assuming the table was empty
Debug.Print DCount("*", "Table1") 'Prints 0
DAO.DBEngine.Rollback
```